# Where did defadt go in new clojure contrib?

Tags: clojure, algebraic-data-types, clojure-contrib

So digging around trying to figure out how to do ADTs in Clojure I run into the old clojure-contrib which is well and good except that it's been replaced. Ok no big deal, just go look through the replaced clojure-contrib's catalog of broken apart libraries, but for the life of me I cannot find where defadt was migrated in the new clojure-contrib broken up libraries.

So where has it migrated to?

I've been looking around http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Clojure+Contrib+Libraries but can't figure it out.

bonus points if you can give me the string to hand to `alembic.still/distill` to get it to plug it in for me.

Comment: This should probably be posted to Programmers.SE

Comment: not really: it's a pretty specific question about a programming library. That's definitely on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual style in Clojure isn't to define ADTs. I'd regard the `defadt` functionality as old / deprecated.

Instead, consider defining your data structures using regular Clojure maps or vectors.

Alternatively you could use `deftype` or `defrecord` if you want a named type which can be used for polymorphic dispatch using protocols. This is a flexible and fast way of getting ADT-like behaviour.

Comment: This is what I had suspected, but thanks for making it clear! I'll stick with records and types then likely as it's more idiomatic.